# How to prevent Eclipse from adding @NotNull annotation when assigning jOOQ expression to local variable

Tags: java, eclipse, jooq, notnull

Starting from jOOQ 3.14, when using jOOQ with code like this:

```java
DSL.val(1);
```

I like to assign the above expression to a local variable, so I'm using the Eclipse IDE quick fix action *"Assign statement to new local variable"*, which adds this import:

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
```

And produces this code:

```java
@NotNull
Param<Integer> val = DSL.val(1);
```

This doesn't happen with IntelliJ whose *"Introduce local variable"* quick fix produces the desired code:

```java
Param<Integer> val = DSL.val(1);
```

How can the unwanted insertion of the `@NotNull` annotation be prevented?

Comment: The root cause is that jOOQ includes null annotations from JetBrains to support the non-vendor-neutral programming language Kotlin and that these null annotations are stored in the bytecode, which is technically not required (and not in line with the Java language specification), but this hack makes it easier for JetBrains to implement their tools. When running an application that uses jOOQ, JetBrains null annotations occupy memory for no reason.

Comment: @howlger: Yes, that's the root cause. Many libraries have started using these annotations, which may have the flaw you're mentioning, but that's not the point here. This question is about the Eclipse quick fix behaviour.

Comment: To be fair, you asked _"How can this be prevented?"_ and it can be prevented by not having null annotations in the bytecode of jOOQ or at least not `TYPE_USE` annotations at methods. Maybe there is already a way (or JetBrains is working on it) to provide Kotlin support without annotations in the bytecode since they are useless at runtime. Or jOOQ (whose author you are) could provide Kotlin support via an additional API/JAR. And the _"pending bug"_ is an enhancement reported by you a couple of months ago and no one seems to be currently working on that "solution" proposed by you.

Comment: *"To be fair, you asked"* - Just pretend someone else asked this question. I'm often using SO as an external FAQ, which is encouraged by SO. *"jOOQ could provide Kotlin support via [...]*" - This was such a low hanging fruit and convenient. I don't think there's a better solution to kotlin nullability support than using such annotations. There's no way back for jOOQ. *"and no one seems to be currently working"* - Sure, no worries. This Q&A here is just intended to help people understand what's going on, and better find how to work around it. I have been asked a few times about this.

Comment: Those who consider to provide Kotlin support for their framework too, should know that this means that annotations will be added to their class files because JetBrains uses a dirty trick. So they might ask JetBrains to fix this. In Eclipse, there is a special behavior for the rarely used `TYPE_USE` annotations that makes sense (in this point we disagree). However, Eclipse could do better by understanding widely used null annotations by default, which would result in different behavior here and better detection of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pending bug in Eclipse to fix this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565463. The rationale of the current behaviour (still present in 2020-12 (4.18.0)) can be seen in that issue.

A workaround is to turn on annotation-based null analysis in Preferences > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Enable annotation-based null analysis

[image]

... and setting the jetbrains annotations as the primary and/or secondary annotations:

[image]

Eclipse may not find the annotations, in case of which a workaround for this may be to manually edit your project's `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file, adding these:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nonnull=org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nullable=org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nullanalysis=enabled
```

The side effect of this workaround is of course that null analysis is now active on jOOQ code, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: This setting does not force you to use null annotations in your own code. You can even suppress displaying of these null problems by setting the severity of those problems to _Ignore_. But why would one not want to get an error when, for example, calling a jOOQ method with a non-null parameter set to null? Does jOOQ contain wrong null annotations?

Comment: @howlger: This Q&A (as well as the linked Eclipse issue) isn't about the Eclipse null analysis feature. I'm just documenting a workaround here for better visibility. Anyway, I've already explained my point of view to you in the issue...

Comment: In the bug report you said that this causes _"having to opt in to the Eclipse null-checking feature"_ and here you say _"that null analysis is now active on jOOQ code"_, which I think that's not true, without explaining it. From my point of view, Eclipse should be improved (1) by having widely used null annotations preconfigured and (2) by not requiring these annotations to be on the Java build path (both by default). In my view, Eclipse behaves for TYPE_USE annotations according to the Java language specification. So there should nothing be changed here. What solution are you proposing?

Comment: @howlger: I'm re-documenting the observed workaround of enabling this Eclipse feature, which, as a *side-effect*, makes annotating client code with `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` go away. My proposed solution is the same as in the Eclipse issue. It should be possible to configure Eclipse to not insert any `TYPE_USE` annotations in client code 1) at all, 2) if they match some include/exclude pattern, 3) some other means of governing which TYPE_USE annotations are of interest, and which ones aren't. Specifically, if the annotation is not on the client classpath, it *must not* be inserted.

Comment: For the same reasons, one could argue that for type returned by a method call Eclipse should insert `Object` for an unknown type and for a generic type its raw type. A `TYPE_USE` annotation on a method refers to what is returned, `TYPE_USE` is not for annotating the method itself. What is wrong with the solution I proposed?

Comment: @howlger: I commented on that here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565463#c21